# PHP MVC Как построить архитектуру для много-ролевого доступа

Tags: php, mvc

Пишу небольшой веб-ресурс для заведения нескольких справочников для большой системы. Есть 3 роли: админ, менеджер, пользователь.

Выбрал вариант, что каждая роль будет на отдельном контроллере со своими вьюшками, или иногда вьюшки можно заимствовать. Но контроллеры отдельные. **Такой вариант нормальный?**

*П.С: выбрал такой вариант, так как если все роли реализовывать в одном контроллере, то код тогда путанным становится, так как у всех ролей свой уровень разрешенных операций, да и иногда вьюшка отличается  по внешнему виду немного. Пришел к выводу за последнее время, что пытаясь избежать дублирования кода, получается еще хуже - тяжеловатый код.*

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет то в ООП подход обычно такой - каждый объект отдельная сущность. Даже если он похож на другой. Вы может их унаследовать  от другого объекта  и тп. но это отдельные сущности. На практике это лично мне сильно помогает т.к условия по ходу реализации могут меняться и если Вы все `похожее` будете заимствовать друг у друга, то когда возникнет ситуация что-то поменять или добавить начнутся проблемы. Это все я к тому, что делайте отдельные контроллеры, модельки, вьюшки даже если они дублируют код в чем-то.

Answer (score 1):

Вы собираетесь под каждую роль создать отдельный контроллер, как вариант, этот выбор решает вашу проблему, но что будет, если ролей у вас станет 100?

С архитектурной точки зрения, такой код будет сложно поддерживать за счет дублирования: отладка/расширение/модификация вашего кода уже будет подразумевать посещение минимум 3-ех мест, которые вы должны держать в голове.

По хорошему, вы должны иметь один контроллер, так же иметь возможность проверить в нем роль и скорректировать относительно этого ваше поведение.

Как вариант: получаете пользователя, который имеет роль, далее, можно организовать фабрику или фабричный метод, для получения соответствующего сервиса и сделать что-то.

```
public function methodOfAnyClass(User $user, UserServicefactory $factory): Response
{
    $role = $user->getRole();

    /**
     * Instance of UserService, ManagerService or AdminService which 
     * implements UserServiceInterface.
     *
     * @var UserServiceInterface $service
     */ 
    $service = $factory->getServiceByUserRole($role);

    $service->doSomething();

    /**
     * @var Response $response
     */
    $response = $service->getSomething();

    return $response;
}
```

Таким образом, у вас будут контроллеры в единственном экземпляре, а логика по работе с разными пользователями будет инкапсулирована в специализированные сервисы.

Comment: Согласен и даже так уже делал. Но тогда сам код становится более запутанным. Вот поэтому решил мнение спросить, снова подойдя к этому вопросу. СПС, принял и обдумываю.

Comment: @yavafree Если выделить четвертую концепцию ООП, это будет абстракция, то тут она просматривается во всей красе, либо же более экстенсивный код (пишите в право), либо же пишете более унифицированный код в единственном экземпляре, так и так что-то более абстрактное получится. Как минимум, пример с 3-мя контроллерами, это решение не по SOLID-у, DependencyInversion - явно не соблюдается.